# What special values exist for HTML <input> `name` attributes?

Tags: html

This is an entirely academic question.

I was recently tracking-down a bug in an application which came down to inadvertently re-using a set of `<input name="..."` attributes on different parts of the same form for some radio buttons. To fix the bug, I had two choices: use random `name` values (this was for a read-only form on the screen, to "review" some previously-entered information) or use *no* `name` attribute at all.

So there are 2 values of the `name` attribute which have special meaning to HTML radio buttons:

1. Using the same name across multiple `<input>` elements (which put them into a radio-button "group")
2. Using *no* name (i.e. empty or actually missing entirely), which puts each one into its own isolated radio-button group (rather than all together in a single group)

Are there other "interesting" values for `name` that cause some behavior other than the above? Not just for radio buttons mind you – for any kind of HTML element.

Answer (score 0):

There are two special cases:

1. `_charset_` : If used as the name of an  element of type hidden, the input's value is automatically set by the user agent to the character encoding being used to submit the form.
2. `isindex`: For historical reasons, the name isindex is not allowed.

A number of user agents historically implemented special support for first-in-form text controls with the name isindex, and this specification previously defined related user agent requirements for it. However, some user agents subsequently dropped that special support, and the related requirements were removed from this specification. So, to avoid problematic reinterpretations in legacy user agents, the name isindex is no longer allowed.

The `name` content attribute gives the name of the form control, as used in form submission and in the form element's elements object. If the attribute is specified, its value must not be the empty string or isindex.

Reference:
[4.10.18.1 Naming form controls: the name attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#attr-fe-name)

Comment: Hah, I remember `isindex` from way back in the day (late 1995 or early 1996 as I remember it). I haven't thought about that in _years_...

Comment: Can you please add spec references to your answer?

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz sure!